# PKCS Signature error/warnings running dmesg on Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, ubuntu-mate, dmesg

I'm on a clean install of Ubuntu Mate 18.04, the system itself is working with no issues, but I am running dmesg to look at errors and warnings. I like to try to get them all dealt with if possible even if they aren't causing obvious issues right now.

I have an Nvidia card running driver 390.48.

I've got most of the issues dealt with, but one that pops up four times says this:

`PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key`

Here are +/- three lines in dmesg for context for two of the occurrences (the second one actually captures two):

```
[    1.157284] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xdf34b000 port 0xdf34b200 irq 126
[    1.157285] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xdf34b000 port 0xdf34b280 irq 126
[    1.157535] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.168128] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    1.168135] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.168138] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.168138] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
```

and:

```
[    1.175479] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 238
[    1.175681] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    1.175734] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.48  Thu Mar 22 00:42:57 PDT 2018 (using threaded interrupts)
[    1.180047] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    1.181035] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  390.48  Wed Mar 21 23:48:34 PDT 2018
[    1.181409] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    1.181814] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
```

The line in question is the PKCS line, I understand the driver will "taint" the kernel. From the context it seems like the PKCS warnings are related to the Nvidia driver. Is that expected? This is the driver obtained from the Ubuntu repository, not independently from Nvidia, if that makes a difference. Usually I can look up the Nvidia-specific errors and warnings (which are usually harmless) but this one I didn't find anything.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/785762/186740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it it seems. Just make sure you delete absolutely everything related to nvidia(purge including all configs and i386 as well).
Make sure `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` returns an empty result.
Then go for:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396
```

(version can vary, of course)

It opens up a graphical interface inside your terminal at some point and proposes to add a signing MOK key. After I did that I rebooted and entered the key when prompted.

Comment: Right, I think this warning has to do with the driver not being signed, which makes no difference if you're not using secure boot (which I wasn't at the time, and I didn't really realize what it was). I've recently started using secure boot, and indeed Ubuntu 18.04 took me to the MOK signing step after a reboot.

Comment: Probably the general case would be getting the correct package from `sudo ubuntu-drivers list`.

Comment: I followed these steps but wasn't presented with the option to sign an MOK key

Comment: @Jonno_FTW, I was prompted when installing Ubuntu 18.04, when I asked it to install proprietary drivers it said it was going to restart and to select a password for the MOK signing. On restart I had to enter that password (after going through a few menus). If you're not using secure boot it may not care? I think that was the case when I originally wrote this question.

Answer (score 3):

I likewise have an  Nvidia card using the proprietary Nvidia driver.

On first boot after upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 by the message:

```
PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

was reported 3 times before reaching the login screen and the boot-sequence
stalled. I could only boot in Recovery Mode. Disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS
made no difference.

Having booted in Recovery Mode, however, I could select `Resume normal boot` from
the action menu and a normal boot sequence then proceeded successfully.

I launched **Software & Updates** and opened the **Additional Drivers** tab.
Under 17.10, my Nvidia graphics card driver had been been the proprietary one
provided by the Ubuntu `nvidia-driver-390` meta-package. Now, the card was *not* reported
as using that proprietary driver, or the open-source `xorg-xserver-video-noveau` driver.
It was shown as using *a manually installed driver*, and the usual proprietary and
open-source driver options were unselectable.

I then established by:

```
dpkg -l nvidia-driver-390
```

that `nvidia-driver-390` was no longer installed. So I installed it:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

Then rebooted, and the boot sequence ran successfully and normally. After
logging in I revisited **Software & Updates** -> **Additional Drivers** and now saw that my graphics card was reported as using the proprietary `nvidia-driver-390`
driver.

Comment: You had a worse situation than me, glad you got it sorted out. Out of curiosity, if you run dmesg | grep -C 3 PKCS do you see something similar to me? For me, it's asymptomatic but I know that can change.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent this issue by first purging the installed NVIDIA driver.
then reboot and also make sure your secure boot is disabled.
go through the installation once more. except this time when the MOK message prompted click "NO" to set a new machine owner key.
worked on Ubuntu 16. NVIDIA-460