# Can see the icons but not the bar

Tags: 16.04, mate

[image: no bar]

This is my desktop. No bar exists. (the version of my Ubuntu is 16.04.6 LTS)

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us if you are using Ubuntu or Ubuntu-Mate?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu-Mate.

Comment: Try `mate-panel --replace &` from the terminal. If you have two monitors - then try to [follow other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127165/66509).

Comment: Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ubuntu Mate, you can launch a terminal using CTRL+ALT+T keys.
In the terminal, type:

```
mate-tweak
```

...and press enter key.
It will launch the Mate Tweak application from which you should be able to select new interface disposition and toolbars.

**Edit:**

Since it did not work, could you please try reinstalling dconf? Steps follow:

```
sudo apt remove --purge dconf-cli
```

Ubuntu will uninstall other packages here. List them and record them for example in a text file for future re-use. For me, with a fresh Ubuntu Mate install, the list was:
`dconf-cli mate-tweak shotwell ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Once done, please reboot:

```
sudo systemctl reboot
```

And then reinstall the packages (use your list of uninstalled packages here, mine might vary as compared to yours):

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli mate-tweak shotwell ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

And now you can try either `mate-tweak` as I suggested before or `dconf reset -f /` as suggested by Sahil Bansal.

Comment: Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header

Comment: Interesting. Could you please update your question with the output of terminal command that follows? ls ".config/"

Comment: bash: .config/: is directory

Comment: Ouch sorry: full command was: ls ".config/"

Comment: Idea was to know what you have in .config directory...

Comment: autostart  folder-color  libreoffice    Pinta           update-notifier
btsync     freeplane     mate           plank           user-dirs.dirs
caja       geany         mate-session   pluma           user-dirs.locale
chromium   geogebra      menus          pulse           variety
compiz-1   gtk-2.0       mimeapps.list  synapse         vlc
dconf      gtk-3.0       mono.addins    Trolltech.conf  yelp
enchant    ibus          opera          ubuntu-mate

Comment: the client i am using has no administrative rights

Comment: Ok. Someone should have admin rights somewhere, so what about contacting an admin? I don't really see any other alternative here unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

The gui settings need to be reseted

```
dconf reset -f /
```

**A word of caution**: Please be mindful that this command will reset all customisation and tweaks you made in your system, including the pinned applications in the Unity launcher or Dock, desktop panel applets, desktop indicators, your system fonts, GTK themes, Icon themes, monitor resolution, keyboard shortcuts, window button placement, menu and launcher behaviour etc.

reference -> https://www.ostechnix.com/reset-linux-desktop-default-settings-single-command/

**And**: 
As the dconf reset command will reset more than just the Unity, GNOME Shell and MATE desktop you should not run it idly — oh, and do make a backup of your existing desktop beforehand, especially if you’ve made extensive customisations and tweaks to any of you the desktops mentioned above.

How? Run dconf dump.

Keep in mind that this command will only affect applications and desktop settings that are stored using dconf/gsettings. It will not reset other apps (e.g., Thunderbird, Google Chrome, Clementine, and so on), affect low-level settings (e.g., drivers, kernel versions, grub), nor will it reset other desktop environments (e.g., KDE Plasma).

reference -> https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/how-to-reset-ubuntu-desktop-to-default

Comment: could you please share problem with this solution?

Comment: Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look into this

Comment: see if this helps
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296231/cannot-save-changes-made-in-gnome-settings

Comment: did it work for you? @xarilaos

Comment: if yes, please mark it as a correct answer, and don't forget to upvote [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296231/cannot-save-changes-made-in-gnome-settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296231/cannot-save-changes-made-in-gnome-settings)